# Selecting text between <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to select text between 
 tags? I am working with the preformatted code below trying to select this data: New York, NY 10012

I've played around with `$('#address').find('br').eq(2).text()`, but know that there must be a better way.

```
    <div id="address">
        Joe Dirt<br>
        PO Box 842<br>
        New York NY 10012<br>
        800-555-5555<br>
        <br>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How would you like to have your text? As array/string?

Comment: It'll be easier if you put your text in `p` elements instead of using `br` elements.

Comment: As a string. I'd only like to select the text.

Comment: @Jeffman extra divs or spans would make more sense though; since it's not a paragraph

Comment: May I ask why you're using jQuery here? `document.getElementByID('address')` would be less overhead.

Comment: I agree with using other elements than `br`. I did not write the html, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrieve the HTML for the `div` and split on the `br` tag:

```
$.trim($("#address").html().split("<br>")[2]);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQgu5/

Comment: You went above the speed limit, take my +1 ;)

Comment: I always forget about `.split()`. Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also wrap the whole thing in a trim and get rid of the whitespace: `$.trim($("#address").html().split("<br>")[2]);`

Comment: @Mark Nice addition.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Portnoy's answer expands on this a bit, to solve for `<br >` & `<br/>`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of selecting the text based on the html you can use the DOM and pick out the appropriate TextNode using the `childNodes` array.

Since the Nodes are counted starting at `0`:

```
address.childNodes[0] # "Joe Dirt"
address.childNodes[1] #   br element
address.childNodes[2] # "PO Box 842"
address.childNodes[3] #   br element
address.childNodes[4] # "New York NY 10012"
address.childNodes[5] #   br element
address.childNodes[6] # "800-555-5555"
address.childNodes[7] #   br element
```

Example code:

```
var address = document.getElementById ("address");
alert(address.childNodes[4].nodeValue);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78evc/

Answer (score 3):

```
var vals = $("#address > br").map(function(i, br) {
    return $.trim(br.previousSibling.data);
}).toArray();
```

Since the text always appears before a `<br>` element, you can select the `br`s and map the `.previousSibling.data` of each to an Array.

This also doesn't suffer from the possibility of HTML rendering being a little different in different browsers, which you can get with HTML parsing approaches.

---

If you just need the one value, then do this:

```
var txt = $.trim($("#address > br")[2].previousSibling.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var line = $("#address").html().split(/<br *\/?>/i)[2];
```

I know it's not "selecting" the line, but as there's no other way with or without jQuery (your solution didn't work for me out-of-the-box), I think it can be a good approach.

Please note it's allowing different ways of writing the <br> tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var html = $('#address').html();
var arr = html.split('<br>');
var data = arr[2]; //the information that you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for this solution to find the text field you want:

```
  $("div")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  })[2];
```

It's presented here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/298758/681538

Why? Because it's delimiter agnostic, and you are really just having a list of text nodes separated with a separator. Since we can get the text nodes with jquery without having to care about what separator you have to adjust to, so why would we?